# New PC will not power on

Tags: boot, motherboard, computer-building

I just finished a new build and nothing happens when I try to power it on (no lights on motherboard, no fans, nothing).

I checked the power supply and it works just fine. The specs are:

- **PSU:** 430 watt
- **Motherboard:** Asus Mini-ITX
- **CPU:** Intel 1150 i5
- **Hard drive:** 1TB
- **Optical drive**

This looks to me like a dead motherboard, but I would not want to send it back without being sure.

Comment: You have connected the panel wires correct ?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/600446/24010

Answer (score 2):

A possible cause could be your PSU not working properly.

The best way to test this would be with a [multimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter), to check if it's providing enough (or any) power.

## If you have a multimeter

> **NOTE:** this requires being careful, and having at least pretty basic electronics knowledge. If you aren't sure of your skills, leave this to a professional, because things could go wrong (breaking your PSU, burning stuff, being shocked...). **You've been warned.**

In case you have access to one, try checking if the voltage values for each pin is correct, as in this picture:

[image: ATX PSU pinout]
*[Picture source](http://upweek.ru/storage/files/posts/64368/Techsupport_Q2_1.jpg)*

For this, you'll probably need to join **pin 16 (PS-ON) to any ground**, because many PSU's don't provide any power unless they're activated. This can be easily done by joining that pin, which usually is the green cable, to any of the black ones.

*If the voltages match, it's very likely the issue is on your motherboard.*

## If you don't have a multimeter

You could still try to join the green cable to ground, to see if when you do that, the PSU's fan turns on.

*If the fan moves, it's probably motherboard's problem.*

However, this is not 100% accurate, so I'd try to test the PSU on other PC, or try with a different PSU, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a light on motherboard indicating that it's receiving power when the power supply is switched on. If you have properly connected both the 24pin and the 4pin power connectors and you're not seeing any lights I would bet the board is dead.

The best way to be sure is to try a different power supply if you have that option.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possible causes.

- Electric cord not carrying power
  Make sure that the wall outlet is working.  If you're using a surge protector, then: good job.  Make sure it is supplying power.  (A turned off surge protector can cause issues.)
- Make sure PSU supplies power
  Many Power Supply Units have a power switch, which can get flipped.  Make sure it is flipped to the ON position.  (Generally, this means pressing the side of the switch that says one ("1"), not zero ("0")
- Make sure motherboard has main power
  There is a set of wires (the exact amount varies based on the connector... maybe 20 or 24 wires) that goes from the PSU to the motherboard.  Some power supply units might have 2 connectors: a 20 pin connector and a 4 pin connector.  Your motherboard may require that they are both connected.
- Look for pins near the CPU
  The CPU fan may require a set of power cables that go to some pins near the CPU, which are specifically meant for the CPU fan.  Without that, the motherboard may realize that the CPU is likely to be insufficiently cooled, and might refuse to do things like power the CPU and power fans.
- Check for damage
  I don't know exactly what safety mechanisms may exist for protecting against things like a short circuit (which may combine positive and negative electrical flows in ways that were not intended/designed), and my guess is that the exact protections may vary (between different computer models, and possibly some "generational" differences as new technical standards are made).  If I checked all the connectors and got no luck, I might do a quick investigation to ensure that nothing looks damaged, including: pins, motherboard, and wires.
- Bad parts
  Bad parts are a possibility.  The issue could be with the power supply unit (PSU) or the motherboard.  For power supply units (PSUs) that use removable cables, a cable could also be an issue.  (For PSUs that don't use removable cables, a cable issue would be the same thing as a PSU issue.)