# Desktop is power looping. Will isolating PSU help me find the cause?

Tags: power-supply

An older desktop is power (boot?) looping.  It will power up for about 2 seconds, some fans will work then it powers off for about 3 seconds and then powers up again - goes through this loop for a long time.  I tried a few things - cleaning, re-seating RAM etc. If I disconnect the PSU from all of the connected components will it be able to at least start up or does the PSU rely on being connected to some component to actually start up?

[image]

Comment: "If I disconnect the PSU from all of the connected components will it be able to start up at least or does the PSU rely on being connected to some component actually to start up?" - You can short the two pins together to test the PSU. Those pins are universal and well documented.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New PC will not power on](https://superuser.com/questions/1018202/new-pc-will-not-power-on)

Answer (score 0):

From
[How to: Test a PSU (Power Supply Unit)](https://help.corsair.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025085372-How-to-Test-a-PSU-Power-Supply-Unit) :

> 1. Shut off your PSU.
> 2. Unplug all cables from the PSU except for the main AC cable and the 24-pin cable.
> 3. Locate pin 16 and pin 17 on your 24-pin cable.
>
> - To find pin 16 and pin 17, count from the left with the clip facing up and the pins facing toward you. They will be the 4th and 5th
>   pins when counting from left to right as shown in the photo example
>   below.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Bend your paper clip so the ends can be inserted into pin 16 and pin 17.
>
> - If you're using a PSU jumper, insert the ends into pin 16 and pin 17.
>
> 5. Turn on the PSU.
> 6. See if the PSU fan turns. If it does, the PSU is functioning normally.